# Osgi runtime environment in Wildfly 8.0.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, wildfly-8

We have a running application on Wildfly 8.0.0 Final , we intend to port this application to osgi runtime for modularity benefits and lowering the footprint of application(Wildfly+application size). But Redhat have stopped supporting OSGi in Wildfly release although community releases have OSGi support. My question is that is it worthwhile to switch to Osgified version of application when Wildfly doesn't officially supports osgi? Is there any other application server which support osgi and ejb container? Our application is intended to deployed for commmercial release in future. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: OSGi and JEE don't generally play well together. Before adding the not-insignificant additional complications of OSGi ask yourself what features you want to use from it and whether you really need them. If it's just modularity, you can do that without OSGi.

Comment: Instead of looking for a way of running OSGi in a JEE container, try with Apache Karaf, it'll give you a modular OSGi Container, which can also be used for Enterprise applications, just with OSGi as basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WildFly uses [JBoss Modules](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home) for modularity. You can look at the [class loading documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) if you'd like to see how you might be able to use JBoss Modules with your deployment.

There is also a separate [JBOSGi for WildFly](https://www.ivanov.biz/projects/jbosgi-for-wildfly/) project you can look at.

Answer (score 1):

For running OSGi apps out of the box: **GlassFish** or **Payara**